# Creating an ontology for an agglutinative language

Tags: ontology

I am sorry if the question is to vague, but I am very new to this concept and don't know where to go.

If you are developing an ontology for a agglutinative language, what is the correct way to identify the terms?

There are not so many examples in English, but :

`telling`, `tell` and  `told` basically refer to same concept. How do you deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of finding base or root form (stem) of inflected or derived words is called [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). There are libraries for doing this, for example [NLTK stem package](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html).